# Force bibliographystyle for single element

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have a collection of literature. Most of that consists of normal publications by human authors, which I cite with the `alpha` style, like this [SDG17].

For some citations, the author is not a human. [This standard](https://saemobilus.sae.org/content/J3016_202104/#revisions) for example says it was published by the `On-Road Automated Driving (ORAD) Committee`, which is fine with me. But I don't want that showing in my Text as [Com21], but rather as for example [SAE21] or maybe even [SAE-J3016].

Can I somehow force different citation texts onto single bib-ids?

At best, there would be something like this:

```latex
\forcecitation{bib-id}{SAE-J3016}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth noting that, with biblatex, you could just use shortauthor or shorthand to do this. But, with bibtex, there is no way but changing the style file, so here it goes :).

1. copy alpha.bst to customalpha.bst
2. In the ENTRY list, add the line `customlabel`
3. Look for

   ```
   FUNCTION {calc.label}
   ```

And replace the existing function body with

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ customlabel empty$
  { type$ "book" =
    type$ "inbook" =
    or
      'author.editor.key.label
      { type$ "proceedings" =
          'editor.key.organization.label
          { type$ "manual" =
              'author.key.organization.label
              'author.key.label
            if$
          }
        if$
      }
    if$
    duplicate$
    year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #2 substring$
    *
    'label :=
    year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$
    *
    sortify 'sort.label :=
  }
  {  customlabel 'label :=
     customlabel 'sort.label :=
  }
  if$
}
```

Basically, I added the test `customlabel empty$` to the beginning and defined what to do if it is not in the end (`customlabel 'label :=` etc.).

On the entry you want to customize, just add the `customlabel` field and things should work.